# Jmeter is converting '@' in the Password into junk character

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I am recording Login in Jmeter. Password has '@'. Jmeter recorded exact string but when i run the same, '@' is converted to '%40ss' and login is getting failed(login is failing even if i pass parameters through csv file). But if we pass parameters through jmeter Body Data, Login is successful. I dont want to pass through Body Data, i want to send parameters through CSV file. How to achieve this. Please find the attachments
[Recorded and Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9GZs.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My expectation is that it is only a matter of representation, i.e. when I run similar request using a sniffer tool like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) I can see `@` sign as a part of form data.

[image: JMeter Form Data At sign]

Most probably your problem lies somewhere else, i.e. you haven't correlated this [`__RequestVerificationToken`](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/09/01/prevent-cross-site-request-forgery-csrf-using-aspnet-mvcs-antiforgerytoken-helper/) or haven't added [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager).

When it comes to load testing ASP.NET web applications you cannot just record and replay your test, you need to perform **correlation** of dynamic parameters, check out [ASP.NET Login Testing with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/aspnet-login-testing-jmeter) article for more details.

Comment: Yes, as u said, problem exist with __RequestVerificationToken. i am following the below links to overcome that.
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27308750/requestverificationtoken-is-not-idetifying-or-getting-assigned-to-variable-by-jm

http://build-failed.blogspot.ae/2012/07/load-testing-aspnet-mvc-part-3-jmeter.html?showComment=1417672985397#c6427302313332055578

Answer (score 0):

Lakshmikanth, when you are passing any special character in parameters values then JMeter converts that character into percent-encoding for eg. '@' converts to '%40', '!' converts to '%21'.

To overcome this issue you can pass your password as it is [say P@ssword] in the .csv file but in your request you need to uncheck the encode checkbox corresponding to your password parameter.[image]